# How to check uploaded file is exists with SFTP using phpseclib

Tags: php, file-upload, sftp, phpseclib, file-exists

I am using phpseclib to upload a file to a remote server. Previously, my script worked fine, but what I am expect is it can check whether the remote server has received the file or not. Such as if file existed return 1/true or if file no existed return 0/false.

My code:

```
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$path = "upload/";
$path_dir .=   $ref .".xml";
$directory = '/home/XML/';
$directory .=   $ref .".xml";

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('xxx.com',22);
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password'))
{
    exit('SFTP Login Failed');
}
echo $sftp->pwd();

$sftp->put($directory, $path_dir, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);

if (!$sftp->get($directory))
{
    echo "0";
}
```

The file uploaded successfully, but don't know how to check the file which whether exists or not.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `file_exists` method:

```
if ($sftp->file_exists($directory))
{
    echo "File exists";
}
```

*(The `$directory` variable name is really confusing here. It's a path to a file not directory.)*

Though it is just enough to test result of the `put` method. The additional check is not really needed.

---

The `file_exists` method is available since phpseclib 0.3.7 only. If you are using an older version of phpseclib, use `stat` method:

```
if ($sftp->stat($directory))
{
    echo "File exists";
}
```

The `file_exists` internally calls the `stat` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do `$sftp->file_exists($directory)`.

Comment: sorry, not working for me. not sure file_exists is sftp has file_exists as I cannot find it in the SFTP examples: [link](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php) but stat($directory) is working fine

Comment: It's line 2250 of the link you provided: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L2250